# Capture SQL server database table changes via MDS(Master Data Services)

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture, mds

We are trying capture a database table Changes via MDS (master data service).

We have created the models in MDS and imported the initial load of data from the database table.

However, we are still not able to capture the table changes in the MDS model.

As of now, we have 2 questions :

1. Is CDC required for MDS to capture table changes ?
2. Is there any explicit mapping in MDS, telling MDS to monitor a specific database table ?

Comment: MDS has nothing to do with capturing changes. To capture changes, you can use Change Tracking or CDC. Change Tracking is lightweight and available in all editions. CDC is heavier and until 2016SP1, it was only available in Enterprise editions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks Panagiotis. So just to be sure, there is no way to capture SQL server changes in MDS. Asking again, as I have searched a lot on internet and I as well didn't find any solution for the above said problem. Plus one of the vendor (for our customer) has already done that, and no one has the details of it and we dont have access to the system as well (so that we can go and check the details)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you developing for?

Comment: What problem? MDS's job is to store master data. Are you asking how to capture changes to MDS tables? Or how to capture and tracking changes to the source data? You can track changes to *any* table with Change Tracking and CDC. You *don't* need something MDS specific - why add something when a single call to `CHANGETABLE(Changes MyTable, @lastCheckVersion)` will return all changes in a table since the last check?

Comment: @robertdeniro we are using SQL sever version 2012.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am asking how to capture and track changes to the source data (a SQL server table). Yes change tracking is a good solution and we also thought about it. thank you.

Comment: Change tracking is lightweight but doesn't give you the before & after data. It can just tell you that a certain column changed. Change Data Capture does give you before & after data, but has more system overhead as it read the transaction log to do what it does. From SQL Server 2016 you can use temporal tables. The are baked right into the table updating system, and are not an add-on like CDC, so have better performance. They also inherently support big data.